LaTex: Small table, that should be flush left, is indenting to the right
I have an errata document. For each errata item, I use a small table, with no borders, to list the Errata ID, Area of operation, Components affected, and Severity. Using a table this way, works, but I cannot get the table to align left with the other section heads.
Here is my main-demo.tex file:

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[hyperindex,hidelinks]{hyperref}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[layout=letterpaper, textheight=9.25in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{phv} \fontseries{m} \selectfont

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.\quad}{0pt}{}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[24pt]{}{24pt}{4pt}

%WATERMARK

\usepackage[fontsize=32pt]{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{ACME Confidential - Internal Use Only}

%FRONT HEADER

\renewcommand\headrule{
  \begingroup
  \color{red}
  \hrule height 2pt width\headwidth
  \endgroup
}

\fancypagestyle{fronthdr}{ 
  \setlength{\topmargin}{-64pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{88pt}
  \setlength{\headsep}{6pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{
    \color{red} \changefontsize{28pt} \flushleft \textbf{Roadrunner} \vspace{-12pt} \\
    \color{black} \changefontsize{16pt} \flushleft Errata}
  \fancyhead[R]{
    \color{red} \changefontsize{28pt} \flushleft \textbf{Roadrunner} \vspace{-12pt} \\
    \color{black} \changefontsize{16pt} \flushleft Errata}
  \fancyfoot{}
} 

%INTERNAL HEADERS/FOOTERS SETUP

\fancypagestyle{plain} {
  \fancyhf{}
  \setlength{\headheight}{48pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{\large \flushleft Roadrunner Errata}
  \fancyhead[R]{\large Internal Errata Sheet}
  \fancyfoot[L]{Rev. 0.x}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain} % execute this command here so the subfiles package will use it
\usepackage{subfiles} % add subfile support

% DOCUMENT SECTION

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fronthdr}
\flushleft {\changefontsize{13pt} Rev 0.x - dd mm 2023 \hspace*{\fill} Internal Errata Sheet}

% TOC

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\begin{center}{\normalsize Table of Contents}\end{center}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\begin{center}{\normalsize Tables}\end{center}}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup

\newpage

\subfile{Demo-topic-internal.tex}

\newpage

\end{document}


The topic Demo-topic-internal.tex is:
% JIRA-3079
% test of subfiles package
\documentclass[main-demo.tex]{subfiles}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Software blows up after starting} \label{SIL-3079}

\begin{tblr}{>{\bfseries}ll}
Errata ID & JIRA-3079 \\
Functional Area & System OS \\
Component & NOC \\
Severity & S5: No workaround \\
\end{tblr}

\subsection*{Description}
After startup, the system locks up.

\subsection*{Impact} 
Reduced performance. 

\subsection*{Symptoms} 
The SW generates a Fault, which is reported as a System Fault. 

\subsection*{Workaround} 
TBD 

\subsection*{Resolution} 
N/A 

\end{document}


Am I using the correct table package? I'd of thought that the table, without any explicit indents, would left align with the subsections.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thaks,
Russ
I was expecting for the initial table, in the errata file, to be left aligned.

x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721859/36296
